# TimedRotatingFileHandler not creating new log file based if scripts run on crontab

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I want to create a rotating system that the log can overwrite logs that are over 30 days. I have tried changing the "when" paramter to "h" and "interval" to 1, it does generate log files in the format

> info.log.2022-05-21_15
> info.log.2022-05-21_16

However, when I tried to use "D" as "when" (Detailed config see code at the bottom ), it just keep appending of the file "info.log" and no action is done when it is over 30 logs.

My python script is running in crontab that run every 15 minutes and runtime is about 2 minutes.

My guess is the TimeRotatingFileHandler can only generate that format of log if the script run non-stop. Am I correct? Are there any other ways to do this kind of Time rotation?

```
    self.logger = logging.getLogger(type(self).__name__)
    self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

   
    self.handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename=os.path.join(log_dir,'info.log'),
                    when='D',
                    interval= 1, 
                    backupCount=30)        
    self.handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    self.formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
    self.handler.setFormatter(self.formatter)
    
    self.logger.addHandler(self.handler)
```